# Bash: Found in script; regarding '*0\ rejected*'

Tags: bash

I'm setting up Check_MK to monitor PowerDNS as well.
I found [this script](https://github.com/Win2ix/Monitoring/blob/master/check_mk/checkpdns) and it works fine.

However, I saw `*0\ rejected*` and `*0\ removed*` in it:

```
if  [[ "$REDISCOVER" == *0\ rejected*  &&  "$REDISCOVER" == *0\ removed* ]]; then
```

I am learning Bash scripting, but I've never seen this before.

Could someone explain what it exactly does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `==` within `[[ ... ]]` in Bash, [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) is performed. In your case, the test will pass only if `"$REDISCOVER"` matches both the patterns `*0\ rejected*` and `*0\ removed*` at the same time.

The pattern `*0\ rejected*` matches strings that:

- `*`: are preceded by zero or more characters;
- `0\ rejected`: contain the string `0 rejected` (the backslash is used to escape the space, so that it is considered as part of the pattern);
- `*`: are followed by zero or more characters.

Or, more simply, `[[ "$REDISCOVER" == *0\ rejected* ]]` checks whether the variable `REDISCOVER` contains the string `0 rejected`.

Similarly for `*0\ removed*`.

Examples of valid values for `REDISCOVER` that will make the test pass are:

```
0 rejected0 removed           # most simple case;
0 removed0 rejected           # order does not matter;
...0 rejected...0 removed...  # there can be arbitrary garbage before,
                              # between or after the two
```

Comment: Hi Andrea. First of all, my apologies for including an URL, I just added it and thought crap, probably not allowed!

Second, thank you for your detailed explanation, that makes everything much clearer!

Comment: @Florius Look up `shell globbing` for more info on the pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Each is a pattern that matches an arbitrary string that contains `0 rejected` (or `0 removed`) somewhere in the string. The backslash is used to quote the whitespace, in preference to 
 `*0" "rejected`. Quoting the entire string `"*0 rejected*"` would not work as desired, because the wildcard characters would be treated literally instead of matching arbitrary strings.